# Splitting a duration of time into several lines no higher than a maximum of 24 hours

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a .csv file that is configured like this table (*with unnecessary data removed*) with playing time in hours, minutes and seconds:

| Date of Broadcasting | Track starting time | Playing Time | Track Title | Main Artist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31-12-2020 | 01:00:00 | 108:03:07 | Dance Monkey | Tones And I |
| 31-12-2020 | 01:00:00 | 106:43:12 | Blinding Lights | The Weeknd |

I need to split the rows into several rows with a duration **no longer than 24:59:00.**

A desired output for the above two lines would look like:

| Date of Broadcasting | Track starting time | Playing Time | Track Title | Main Artist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31-12-2020 | 01:00:00 | 24:00:00 | Dance Monkey | Tones And I |
| 31-12-2020 | 01:00:00 | 24:00:00 | Dance Monkey | Tones And I |
| 31-12-2020 | 01:00:00 | 24:00:00 | Dance Monkey | Tones And I |
| 31-12-2020 | 01:00:00 | 24:00:00 | Dance Monkey | Tones And I |
| 31-12-2020 | 01:00:00 | 12:03:07 | Dance Monkey | Tones And I |
| 31-12-2020 | 01:00:00 | 24:00:00 | Blinding Lights | The Weeknd |
| 31-12-2020 | 01:00:00 | 24:00:00 | Blinding Lights | The Weeknd |
| 31-12-2020 | 01:00:00 | 24:00:00 | Blinding Lights | The Weeknd |
| 31-12-2020 | 01:00:00 | 24:00:00 | Blinding Lights | The Weeknd |
| 31-12-2020 | 01:00:00 | 10:26:48 | Blinding Lights | The Weeknd |

I have access to Excel, Access and Python. I have tried accomplishing the task in Python, but I'm running my head against the wall trying to figure out the remainder of the minutes:

```
import csv
from math import ceil

def get_hour(hhmmss):
    time = hhmmss[2]
    split_time = str(time).split(":")

    return int(split_time[0])

with open('2020_Beat_weighted.csv') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
    next(csv_reader, None)

    for row in csv_reader:
        hour = get_hour(row)

        if hour > 24:
            divider = ceil(hour / 24)
            print("--")
            print(hour)
            print(divider)

            for x in range(divider):
                print(row)
                # here, print last row with remaining hours and minutes
```

Here's a raw example of the file 2020_Beat_weighted.csv:

```
Date of Broadcasting;Track starting time;Track playing time;GramexID;Side;Tracknummer;Album Title;Track Title;Main Artist;ISRC-code;Record label;Catalogue no;Country of Recording;Year of first release;Local ID
31-12-2020;01:00:00;108:03:07;;;;;Dance Monkey;Tones and I;;;;;;8a8c04f4-a3db-4d05-83c5-42061434a088
31-12-2020;01:00:00;106:43:12;;;;;Blinding Lights;The Weeknd;;;;;;a39f14c3-d3a3-49f2-83fb-e2ea9fede5e4
```

Comment: If you learn to use the `datetime` type, you'll find this much easier.  You trivially convert the given time to a `timedelta`, read off the quantity of days for your first `N` lines, and take the remainder for the final line.

Comment: Great suggestion, I managed to work out the solution quite quickly if inelegantly looking into timedelta. I will add my changes below for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

Using Prune's suggestions, I modified my code to use timedelta and arrived at this snippet to calculate the days and the remainder:

```
with open('2020_Beat_weighted.csv') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
    next(csv_reader, None)

    for row in csv_reader:
        h,m,s = row[2].split(":")

        time = timedelta(hours=int(h),minutes=int(m),seconds=int(s))

        if time.days>1:
            for days in range(time.days):
                print(
                    row[0]+";"+
                    row[1]+";"+
                    "24:00:00"+";"+
                    row[3]+";"+
                    row[4]+";"+
                    row[5]+";"+
                    row[6]+";"+
                    row[7]+";"+
                    row[8])
            print(
                row[0]+";"+
                row[1]+";"+
                str(time-timedelta(days=time.days))+";"+
                row[3]+";"+
                row[4]+";"+
                row[5]+";"+
                row[6]+";"+
                row[7]+";"+
                row[8]
                    )
```